# iphone development explained?

Tags: iphone

i am very new to iphone development. however i have some experience in flex(flash) and web (ajax) development experience. can u guy suggest some good resources for people like me.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the iOS community first of all; for the most rich and detailed resources I'd go to Apple's Dev Website (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). The Apple Dev forums (https://devforums.apple.com) is a great area to ask questions to developers; especially concerning NDA-builds (i.e. the current NDA build is the 4.2 beta). stackoverflow is a great area too!

Hope I answered your question! :)